# Animation not work when second run

Tags: iphone, animation

I´m running this code to scale and move an image in animation. It works perfectly the first run, but the next time I run this code the image does not animate.
I´ve put NSLog statements before and after the transforms to see if the image is affected. See the results below the code

```
-(void)animateShowImage:(UIButton *)button
{
     //set the starting animate position
     CGRect frameRect = imageView.frame;

     frameRect.size.width = button.frame.size.width;
     frameRect.size.height = button.frame.size.height;
     frameRect.origin = button.frame.origin;
     imageView.frame = frameRect;


     NSLog(@"imageview width : %f", imageView.frame.size.width);
     NSLog(@"imageview height : %f", imageView.frame.size.height);
     NSLog(@"imageview x : %f", imageView.frame.origin.x);
     NSLog(@"imageview y : %f", imageView.frame.origin.y);

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];

     CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(30, 20);
     CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3,3);

     CGAffineTransform finalTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(move, scale);
     imageView.transform = finalTransform;

     [UIView commitAnimations]; 

     NSLog(@"imageview width : %f", imageView.frame.size.width);
     NSLog(@"imageview height : %f", imageView.frame.size.height);
     NSLog(@"imageview x : %f", imageView.frame.origin.x);
     NSLog(@"imageview y : %f", imageView.frame.origin.y);
}
```

NSLog first run:

```
2009-10-19 19:13:41.339 MyProject[15847:207] imageview width : 48.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:41.341 MyProject[15847:207] imageview height : 45.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:41.341 MyProject[15847:207] imageview x : 8.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:41.342 MyProject[15847:207] imageview y : 57.000000
(gdb) continue
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2009-10-19 19:13:44.649 MyProject[15847:207] imageview width : 144.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:44.650 MyProject[15847:207] imageview height : 135.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:44.650 MyProject[15847:207] imageview x : 50.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:45.080 MyProject[15847:207] imageview y : 72.000000
```

NSLog second run:

```
2009-10-19 19:13:51.487 MyProject[15847:207] imageview width : 48.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:51.488 MyProject[15847:207] imageview height : 45.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:51.489 MyProject[15847:207] imageview x : 8.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:51.489 MyProject[15847:207] imageview y : 57.000000
(gdb) continue
2009-10-19 19:13:54.424 MyProject[15847:207] imageview width : 48.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:54.425 MyProject[15847:207] imageview height : 45.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:54.425 MyProject[15847:207] imageview x : 8.000000
2009-10-19 19:13:57.433 MyProject[15847:207] imageview y : 57.000000
```

I can´t figure out what I´m doing wrong. Any help is apprechiated!

Comment: Please add your problem inline.

Comment: @Georg - you've got 18k reputation - you can edit it yourself ;)

Comment: @deanWombourne: I could have, but formatting everything nicely was more work than I was willing to spend for something the OP should have done in the first place (for once). Thanks for doing it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the transform before you can apply a second animation. At the start of the method you can add:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

I don't have enough understanding of CoreAnimation to properly explain why this is needed, but hopefully someone with that knowledge will stumble upon this question and enlighten us.

*Tip:* If you find yourself in need of writing out CGRect and CGPoint you can use the convenience methods NSStringFromCGRect and NSStringFromCGPoint.

```
NSLog(@"imageView.frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame));
```